# Checking for Model Errors in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my controller, I have an action that takes in 3 arguments (primary_key, property, and value) and uses reflection to set the value on corresponding model. (Found by its primary key)

I thought I could catch the model if it was invlaid with `ModelState.IsValid` but it evaluates as true. Now it goes to `db.SaveChanges();` which throws exception.

The `ModelState` is valid. (Apparently it is no the model instance as found by the primary key and actually refers to my three inputs).

I thought I could check my model for errors with the following line...

```
if (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationResult.ValidationErrors.Empty)
```

But I am getting a "missing object reference" error.

I have no idea what that means. (New to C# and everything else here.) Any help?

EDIT 1 - SHOW MORE CODE:

Validations

```
[Column("pilot_disembarked")]
[IsDateAfter(testedPropertyName: "Undocked", 
             allowEqualDates: true, 
             ErrorMessage = "End date needs to be after start date")]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> PilotDisembarked { get; set; }
```

Custom Validatior

```
public sealed class IsDateAfter : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private readonly string testedPropertyName;
    private readonly bool allowEqualDates;

    public IsDateAfter(string testedPropertyName, bool allowEqualDates = false)
    {
        this.testedPropertyName = testedPropertyName;
        this.allowEqualDates = allowEqualDates;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var propertyTestedInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(this.testedPropertyName);
        if (propertyTestedInfo == null)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(string.Format("unknown property {0}", this.testedPropertyName));
        }

        var propertyTestedValue = propertyTestedInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

        if (value == null || !(value is DateTime))
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        if (propertyTestedValue == null || !(propertyTestedValue is DateTime))
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        // Compare values
        if ((DateTime)value >= (DateTime)propertyTestedValue)
        {
            if (this.allowEqualDates)
            {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }
            if ((DateTime)value > (DateTime)propertyTestedValue)
            {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }
        }

        return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
    }
 }
```

Controller Action

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult JsonEdit(string name, int pk, string value)
    {
        Voyage voyage = db.Voyages.Find(pk);

        var property = voyage.GetType().GetProperty(name);

        if (Regex.Match(property.PropertyType.ToString(), "DateTime").Success)
        {
            try
            {
              if (Regex.Match(value, @"^\d{4}$").Success)
              {
                var newValue = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "HHmm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                property.SetValue(voyage, newValue, null);
              }
              else if (value.Length == 0)
              {
                  property.SetValue(voyage, null, null);
              }
              else
              {
                var newValue = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "yyyy/MM/dd HHmm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                property.SetValue(voyage, newValue, null);
              }
            }
            catch
            {
                Response.StatusCode = 400;
                return Json("Incorrect Time Entry.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var newValue = Convert.ChangeType(value, property.PropertyType);
            property.SetValue(voyage, newValue, null);
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
            Response.StatusCode = 200;
            return Json("Success!");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 400;
            return Json(ModelState.Keys.SelectMany(key => this.ModelState[key].Errors));
        }

    }
```

Comment: You need to show us more of your code.  Show us the model and the function throwing the exception.

Comment: @Amy - Added more code...!

Comment: What line is throwing the Exception?

Answer (score 0):

When any value of your model is null at that time **ModelState.IsValid**.So first check your model data.